# Convert tkinter window content to an image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to convert tkinter window content to a .bmp image (or other type of image files) and save the result in a directory selected by the user. How can I do this conversion?

The code for saving is as follows:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="Hello").grid(row=1, sticky='w')

dir_path=filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/", title="Choose a folder")
if len(dir_path)>0:
    Element= ...# Here I want to put the .bmp image resulting in the conversion of the created tkinter window 
    Element_name="image_1.bmp"
    file_path=os.path.join(dir_path, Element_name)
    Element.save(file_path, "BMP")
```

Comment: Please, could somebody help me?

Comment: You can export the content of a Canvas in .ps, but otherwise you will need to take a screenshot if you want the full window, e.g. with [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/).

Comment: @j_4321 In the complete code, I have an Excel file and a canvas must be created for each sheet of this file (ie in the complete code, a part of the posted code is in a loop). So, for each of the created canvas, I can't open the image (which is not created yet (since I have only the .ps file) and take a screenshot) .

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You are talking about opening an image while I thought you wanted to save the window as an image. Maybe if you edit your question to say more clearly what you want to do, someone might answer.